# The scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region

Tags: azure

I want publish my web application (ASP.NET Core 3.1) on Microsoft Azure by Visual Studio 2019.

Also I have **free trial** account.

I have selected "West Us 2" for Hosting plan and databases.
After clicking on create button, I got this errors.

How can I fix it?

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
>   {"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template
>   deployment 'website_deployment_20200410034706' is not valid according
>   to the validation procedure. The tracking id is
>   '129c8a5a-87ac-468c-9773-49d327f0164c'. See inner errors for
>   details.","details":[{"code":"ValidationForResourceFailed","message":"Validation
>   failed for a resource. Check 'Error.Details[0]' for more
>   information.","details":[{"code":"RegionClosedForSubscription","message":"The
>   scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region.
>   Try selecting different region or scale option."}]}]}}    at
>   Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Provisioning.DeploymentManager.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Client.Http.HttpResponseExtensions.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Client.Navigation.ARMRootExtensions.d__7`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Client.Navigation.EntityExtensions.<PutAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Provisioning.DeploymentManager.d__16.MoveNext()

**And this:**

> Template deployment failed. Deployment operation statuses: Failed:
>   /subscriptions/67b8d9e3-af75-4f27-b8b2-e581625c149c/resourcegroups/ondotnet19/deployments/website_deployment_20200410034706
>   (exception) error (HttpRequestException):
>   {"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template
>   deployment 'website_deployment_20200410034706' is not valid according
>   to the validation procedure. The tracking id is
>   '129c8a5a-87ac-468c-9773-49d327f0164c'. See inner errors for
>   details.","details":[{"code":"ValidationForResourceFailed","message":"Validation
>   failed for a resource. Check 'Error.Details[0]' for more
>   information.","details":[{"code":"RegionClosedForSubscription","message":"The
>   scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region.
>   Try selecting different region or scale option."}]}]}}

Comment: Please take a look at [this statement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/) and [this statement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/) about Azure continuity during the covid-19 crisis. Unfortunately, aside from suggesting you open a support ticket, there's nothing that can be done here at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We’re implementing a few temporary restrictions designed to balance the best possible experience for all of our customers. **We have placed limits on free offers to prioritize capacity for existing customers.** We also have limits on certain resources for new subscriptions. These are ‘soft’ quota limits, and customers can raise support requests to increase these limits. If requests cannot be met immediately, we recommend customers use alternative regions (of our 54 live regions) that may have less demand surge. To manage surges in demand, we will expedite the creation of new capacity in the appropriate region.

Recently, many peoples have the same problem.

As you are the **free trial** account, you may affect by the [limit](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/). Like david suggested, you can open a support ticket to propose your need.

Comment: Transient issues like this really don't fit on Stack Overflow, as they become obsolete in relatively short order (plus this isn't a programming question - it's directly related to service availability). This is why I didn't post as an answer, and left an explanation in the comments.